# Swapping Rockshox TwistLoc lockout to trigger lockout

Tags: trek, lockout

I have a Trek Top Fuel 8 with a Rockshox TwistLoc lockout system. Can I switch it for a trigger lockout?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe the Top Fuel has a Rockshox Recon shock - Rockshox have a ["Remote upgrade Kit"](https://www.sram.com/en/rockshox/models/ss-rmtk-xloc-a1) for the job (Make sure the kit matches your shock) . Not particularly hard to do yourself, but you may prefer to get the LBS to to do it if you are no familiar with shock servicing procedures.